# The filter does not appear if the id number is empty in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to make a multi filter, one of them with an id number, but before entering the id number no data appears.

```
 $postlocations = $postlocationsquerynew
                ->whereHas('postlog', function (Builder $querypost) use($request){
                    $log = $request->log;
                    $id = $request->id;
                    $querypost->where('id', $id)->where('log', 'like', '%' . $log . '%')->where('id', $id);
                })
                ->get();
```

Comment: r u sure there is a postlog have that id and log?

Comment: yes i'm sure,  if I have an id for example 3, it wants to appear, but when the form with the get id method is empty, the data does not appear that I want all the data to appear

Comment: You can add default id to `$postlocations` check if `$postlocations == null` then `$postlocations = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [when](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses) to apply `$q->where('id', $id)->where('log', 'like', '%' . $log . '%')` statement if a given `$id` value is present:

```php
$postlocations = $postlocationsquerynew
                ->whereHas('postlog', function (Builder $querypost) use($request){
                    $log = $request->log;
                    $id = $request->id;
                    $querypost->when($id, function($q, $id) use ($log) {
                           $q->where('id', $id)->where('log', 'like', '%' . $log . '%');
                    });
                })
                ->get();
```

Comment: How to add more filter with that script ?

Comment: @AgusyogiSumanjaya just add another `$querypost->when($another_param, function($q, $id) ....`

Comment: i would like to add filter between report date, this code is not work.
`->when($report_start, $report_finish, function($querydate_start, $report_start, $report_finish) use ($log) {
                        $querydate_start->whereBetween('report_date', [$report_start, $report_finish])->where('log', 'like', '%' . $log . '%');
                    })`

Comment: @AgusyogiSumanjaya what is `$report_start ...`I think you need to post a new question.

Comment: @AgusyogiSumanjaya `when($parameter, callback)`. and `when` only support one parameter

Comment: $report_start is start date , and $report_finish is finish date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206954/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-agusyogi-sumanjaya).